# Restrict access for a virtual URL path that is reverse proxied from Apache 2.4 to Tomcat backend

Tags: apache, tomcat

How can I configure restriction for URL generated by opencms application on Apache Tomcat?

I tried

```
<Location "/cs/intranet">
order deny,allow
deny from all
allow from XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX
</Location>
```

But folder does not exist physically, just url.

```
http://DOMAIN/cs/intranet
```

**Edit.**

Something like this?

```
<RequireAll "/cs/intranet">
    Require all denied
    Require ip XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX
</RequireAll>
```

Comment: What you tried looks like configuration for Apache server, not for Tomcat.  Tomcat configuration is pure XML as far as I know.   Is your Tomcat server running as a backend behind an Apache reverse proxy?

Comment: @StephenOstermiller Yes, it is running as a backend behind an Apache reversy proxy.

Comment: What version of Apache?  The `order` and `deny` are for Apache 2.2 and earlier.   Apache 2.4 and later should use the `require` keyword.  See https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/access.html There is a backwards compatibility module for 2.4 but I've only gotten it to work in *.htaccess*.  If you are making those changes in a `.conf` file under 2.4, you'll need the new syntax.   Which file did you try that in?

Comment: @StephenOstermiller `Server version: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu)`. I don't understand how can I use `Require` for my issue? No `.htaccess` file is possible, just `conf`. See my edit. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the end, `ProxyMatch` is the way to do it.

```
<ProxyMatch "/cs/interni" >
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX
</ProxyMatch>
```

Thanks to all.

Answer (score 1):

It should be as simple as:

```
<Location "/cs/intranet">
    require ip XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX
</Location>
```

The [Upgrading to 2.4 from 2.2 - Apache HTTP Server Version 2.4](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/upgrading.html) document gives a similar example of upgrading from:

```
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from all
Allow from example.org
```

to:

```
Require host example.org
```

because the default under 2.4 if it doesn't meet the requirement, the request is denied.

Your use of `<Location>` is correct.  According to [the core documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#location) that is to match the URL, and not necessarily a directory in the file system.

Comment: Thanks, but seems it is not working. I tried various combinations and site is still accessible.